# System command not working in Ruby and returning false?

Tags: java, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to run a Java program, which is a standalone application, from Ruby. I am using the following commands in Ruby:

```
system("cd /home/webserver/testproject"); 
system("sh testsh.sh")
```

My Java project is available in "/home/webserver/testproject", so I am changing the directory using the first command. The sh file writes a file which contains info to run my main class and also sets the `CLASSPATH` environment variable to run program. When doing this outside of Ruby it's working properly but not inside Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

`system` makes a new subshell every time you run it, so you always start in the current directory. What you need is to change the directory inside Ruby with `Dir.chdir`:

```
Dir.chdir("/home/webserver/testproject") do
  system "sh testsh.sh"
end
```

The change in the working directory will only be applied to the code inside the `do` … `end` block. If you want to make the change permanent for the whole script, you can do it this way:

```
Dir.chdir "/home/webserver/testproject"
system "sh testsh.sh"
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `system("cd ...` changes the current working directory *only inside the scope of the command*. To run the second command in the correct directory, you need to chain them:

```
system("cd /home/webserver/testproject && sh testsh.sh")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot working now. And one more doubt is, Actually i am running sh file in that it generates some logger info which i want capture in ruby.

Comment: @user2436481 That would be an excellent, separate question.  But before you ask it, perhaps you'll find the answer here: http://mentalized.net/journal/2010/03/08/5_ways_to_run_commands_from_ruby/